# Search for string with VLOOKUP in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

Trying to find a particular string in a google sheet column (column A) and return the value of the cell directly to the right (column B). If tried the following, but keep getting a Formula parse error. Please advise:

=VLOOKUP(“Assessment Guide - AWG”, A16:B120,2,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

That formula looks right to me, but if you could take a screenshot of how you wrote the formula that would be helpful. Usually formula parsing issues happen when you use a semicolon instead of a comma or have an extra parenthesis or a quote in the wrong place.